# OSGi: Get list of classes in package

Tags: osgi

Is it possible to find all classes or interfaces in a given package? There is no simple way to do it in "plain Java", but OSGi probably does a better job, doesn't it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is yes starting in 4.3. A new API has been added:

[BundleWiring.listResources(String path, String filePattern, int options)](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleWiring.html#listResources%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)

which can be used to scan the class path of a bundle. With the appropriate parameters, you can get the names of all the classes in a package.

Comment: Cool, I didn't see that one yet!

Answer (score 0):

In short: No. OSGi extends the Java classloading mechanism by providing classes when they are needed, but there is no API that allows you to inspect which classes are available in a given package.

Comment: Interesting, because the "Java way" of doing it (take the jar from classpath and introspect it) ceased to work in OSGi.

Comment: Ah, I see. Both systems use a mechanism in which a class has a fully qualified name, and you ask a classloader "get me this class"; in that sense, nothing changed, but the way in which the correct class is picked is different. If you really want to, you can still find out whose package you're using, and inspect the bundle yourself. In that case, you still run into problems if multiple bundles provide the same package, containing different classes; I wouldn't advise you to, unless you have a very specific use case.

Comment: I mean - I can't get the jar file, so I can't dig into it.

Comment: Not only is there listResources on the new BundleWiring API that is well suited, there always has been getEntryPaths on bundle that allow you to get the same information albeit in a more complex form because you have to understand the Bundle Class Path.
There is no defined way in Java to get the JAR and iterate over it because the source of your classes might not even be a JAR ... Many people are doing it but it is a disaster waiting to happen and not portable.